# Overleaf Free-Tier Sharing and History

Tags: overleaf

I have free tier on Overleaf, and I'm wondering if users with the link to edit my document can see the history of my document? And if the users with the link are premium users, can they see the full history?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions are best posted to the Overleaf Helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have premium and have shared a link, they can see the history as well as edit if you give them that option, otherwise they have a view only option. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_the_History_feature#:%7E:text=Only%20the%20project%20owner%20needs,to%20access%20the%20full%20history.)